# Tomcat view catalina.out log file

Tags: linux, tomcat

In Red Hat,

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat
tail -f logs/catalina.out
```

I can see the log in the console.

In Ubuntu,

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat6
tail -f logs/catalina.out
```

Nothing show out in the console.

May I know what is the problem? Which configuration that I need to look to?

Comment: Are you sure that `logs/catalina.out` exists?

Comment: `tail` would have reported an error if the file did not exist.

Comment: Yes the catalina.out is in the folder.

Comment: I already checked the log moved to a file called catalina.[YYYY-MM-DD].log but the catalina.out is always in 0 file size. May I know where can I see the setting and configuration for logging? [ catalina.out is in green colour and catalina.[YYYY-MM-DD].log is grey colour in console ] Thanks -fsloke

Answer (score 57):

Tomcat 7 Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS:

```
tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
```

Comment: The point is `tail -f <some_folder_under_tomcat>/catalina.out`.

Answer (score 22):

`locate catalina.out` and find out where is your catalina out. Because it depends.

If there is several, look at their sizes: that with size 0 are not what you want.

Answer (score 14):

```
 cd /usr/local/tomcat/logs
 tail -f catalina.out
```

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes it is located in different places. It depends on the server.
You can use `find` to find it:

```
 find / -name catalina.out
```

If you encounter permission issues, add `sudo` to the command:

```
sudo find / -name catalina.out
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 4):

I found mine at

```
~/apache-tomcat-7.0.25/logs/catalina.out
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

```
sudo tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for me on Ubuntu...
cd var/lib/tomcat7 
sudo nano logs/catalina.out

Answer (score 2):

I have used this command to check the logs and `10000` is used to show the number of lines

```
sudo tail  -10000f catalina.out
```

Comment: I have added the title as well for "what is the purpose of this command".Any other change?

Comment: nope... bots are now less prone to mark your answe for LQ-post award. Removed my clutter/comments as you can see ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just logged in to the server and type below command

```
locate catalina.out
```

It will show all the locations where `catalina` file exist within this server.

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware also that catalina.out can be renamed - it can be set in /bin/catalina.sh with the CATALINA_OUT environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the home directory first move to apache tomcat use below command

```
cd apache-tomcat/
```

then move to logs

```
cd logs/
```

then open the catelina.out  use the below command

```
tail -f catalina.out
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type in the command line

```
catalina
```

you will see some message about it, look for this:

**CATALINA_BASE**:   /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.27/libexec

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.27/libexec/logs
tail -f catalina.out
```

You will then see the live logs.

NOTE: My Tomcat installation was done via **Homebrew**

Answer (score 0):

I found logs of Apache Tomcat/9.0.33    version in below path:

In tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the commands together so you will not miss seeing even first line of the log while trying to locate the LOG location.

```
cd /usr/local/tomcat/logs; tail -f catalina.out;
```